# How to remove string in dynamic content using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a dynamic strings that outputs,

```
test-only
test-only-1
test-only-12
sample-only-2
sample-test-55
etc...
```

I would like to ask, how can i remove -1,-12,-2, -55 dynamically using php?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps do not put them in there in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/-[0-9]+$/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work when all of the input is on the same line.

```
preg_replace('/([a-z\-]+)(-[0-9]+)/', '$1', $data);
```

With input on multiple lines it would be best to anchor to the end of the string

```
preg_replace('/^([a-z\-]+)(-[0-9]+)$/', '$1', $data);
```

Comment: This is missing the ending `$`

Comment: this was written before I notice he changed the input from a single line to multiline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace to replace with a regex. $string in the example below would be the text you are trying to fix. This will replace - and /d+ will replace numeric characters.

```
$pattern = '/\-/d+$/i';
print preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```